# How to generate random number and check if it already exists in database using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm working on a project where I am helping build a website for a Theater group using an ASP.NET MVC web app and Entity Framework. They want to be able to rent out their space to other groups and to do that a form was created on the website for people to submit applications. I was tasked to create a rental code attribute that generates a random 5 digit code and assigns that value to the attribute. I have been able to get the number to generate and assign it to the rental code attribute.

At this point I am trying to make it so when the number is generated the program runs a loop and checks the database to make sure that number doesn't already exist. And if it does exist, I want it to generate a new number then check that, and keep doing so until it has a unique number. Then assign that number to the rental code attribute.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    db.RentalRequests.Add(rentalRequest);
    var randomNum = new Random();
    int codeNum = randomNum.Next(10000, 99999);
    rentalRequest.RentalCode = codeNum;

    db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Please let me know if any other data is need from me to figure this out. Anything that could put me in the right direction is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you use and identity field? You will not succeed in a scaleable, maintainable solution if you check every row every time you enter a new record.

Comment: Any idea why they want it to be random? Not exactly military grade security if it's only 5 digits.

Comment: Build a table with numbers 10000 (inclusive) to 99999 (exclusive) and have a flag to indicate if they are used. Use that to set the RentalCode. The "generate random number, check if it's used, repeat until unused number found" loop will take a really long time as you approach ~90,000 rentals. At the low end, you have around a 1 in 89,998 chance that your generated code won't be unique, but at the high end you'll have a 89,997 in 89,998 chance that your code isn't unique.

Comment: Databases are able to auto generate, unique, auto increment numbers as IDs. I would recommend as well to use that kind of field in DB rather than using random number / lookup loop thing.

Answer (score 0):

Given it's a relatively small number of possible IDs, I would instead look at holding a ID assignment table consisting of:

RentalCode: Int [PK] (Identity: Start 10000, Increment: 1)

Sequence: GUID  (Default: NewId()  Unique Index)

IsAssigned: Bit (Default: false)

With that table created, Insert the 89999 rows which would give you the 10000 - 99999. With the Default and Identity columns you just need an insert to create the row without supplying any fields.

Create an entity for this table.

When you want to assign a rental code to a new Theatre Group:

```
using(var context = new AppContext())
{
    var rentalCode = context.RentalCodes.Where(x => !x.IsAssigned)
        .OrderBy(x => x.Sequence)
        .FirstOrDefault();
    if(rentalCode == null)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("All rental codes are assigned.");

    rentalCode.IsAssigned = true;
    context.SaveChanges();  // Fetch our next free code, mark it as assigned, and save changes quickly to minimize concurrency risk.

    var theatreGroup = new TheatreGroup
    {
        // fill in details...
        RentalCode = rentalCode.RentalCode;
    }
    context.TheatreGroups.Add(theatreGroup);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

The NewId() GUID gives you a reasonably random order that you can sort the rental codes by repeatedly. Sorting then taking the first unassigned row will give you a quick random code without the need to generate, check, and retry, which would hit more collisions as the number of assigned rental codes are used.

The key here would be to have the code reserve a rental code up front and save the updated assigned marked code as quickly as possible. This will help prevent 2 or more requests from trying to use the same rental code for new groups.

The RentalCode on your TheatreGroup should have a unique constraint, so this code, or the calling code should catch a `DbUpdateException` from EF in the (very) rare concurrency situation where two theatre groups are created at roughly the same time and the 2nd tries to insert with the same rental code. The above code would take steps to reduce this possiblity, but does not prevent it. An exception here should simply retry the operation.

If you delete a TheatreGroup you can release the rental code by setting it's assigned flag back to False. (Or don't, if you don't want the codes to be reused.)

Alternatively the RentalCode can be treated as a FK from TheatreGroup to RentalCode table/entity and you can avoid the IsAssigned flag and just relying on the association to find the next unassigned one:

```
using (var context = new AppDbContext())
{
    var rentalCode = context.RentalCodes
        .Where(x => x.TheatreGroup == null)
        .OrderBy(x => x.Sequence)
        .FirstOrDefault();

    // ...
}
```

This would rely on a `HasOptional(x => x.TheatreGroup).WithRequired(x => x.RentalCode)` between the rental code and theatre group. This approach would make recycling rental codes a lot cleaner, but would widen the window for multiple processes to try and reserve the same rental code.